# Django verbose_name of reverse relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-related-manager

I have a model like:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='answers',
        verbose_name='translated name'
)
```

I would now like to use the `verbose_name` in a template (as it is translated) over the reverse relation like

`{{  question.answers.verbose_name }}`. Unfortunately this does not work.

On the other hand `{{  question.answers.related_name }}` works.

So it seems that in the reverse_relation only the `related_name` is available.

Is there any way to get the `verbose_name` from the reverse relation?

Comment: I'd like this too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No verbose name is just to make the model name more readable.
They are used if you want to make your model attribute more readable.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name

> A human-readable name for the field. If the verbose name isn’t given,
> Django will automatically create it using the field’s attribute name,
> converting underscores to spaces. See Verbose field names.